# What is the -D switch in rsync?

Tags: rsync

What is the `-D` switch in rsync?
Okay manpage says

```
-D                          same as --devices --specials
-g, --group                 preserve group
    --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
    --specials              preserve special files
```

But

- What are device files?
- What are special files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From rsync man pages:

```
--specials
          This option causes rsync to transfer special files such as named
          sockets and fifos.
```

So special files may be symbolic links (which are references to other files on the file system, think shortcuts in Windows) but also sockets and fifos (pipes) that are used for inter-process communication.

Device files are another variety of special files that represent devices provided by the kernel.

If you want to know more, look at [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types).